# ListView with date as section headers position varies onScroll

Tags: android, listview, sectionheader

Im trying to load custom callLogs in a `listView` based on date as section header.In `ListAdapter` i compare each date with the previous date and set `SectionHeaderLayout` Visible/Invisible. When the `ListView` has been loaded the section header are displayed correctly but when i scroll the section headers are set Visible to wrong `ListItems`.

Please help me to figure out a solution.

This is how im trying to set `SectionHeader` through the `adapter`.

```
    if (position == 0) {

        checkDate = mDateStr;
        holder.sectionHeaderDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.sectionHeaderText.setText(mDateStr);
         }
        } else if (checkDate == null || !checkDate.equals(mDateStr)) {

            checkDate = mDateStr;
            holder.sectionHeaderDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.sectionHeaderText.setText(mDateStr);

        } else {
            holder.sectionHeaderDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old question, you have probably solved your problem, but I'll answer for others who will have the same problem.

If you want to show header based on previous date you can't do that by remembering last item that was passed to getView function. 
The reason is scrolling, i.e. different direction when going up and down. 
For example, if you have items 
1,
2,
3,
4,
5

when you're going down, and current item is 3, previous was 2, and all will work. 
But if you are going up, your previous item for 3 was actually 4, and that's where your problem happens.

so instead of keeping item, you should use positions.

this would be the sketch of solution that you can call inside of your getView function:

```
private void showHeader(ViewHolder holder, Call item, int position) {

    boolean shouldShowHeader = false;
    if (position == 0
            || !DateHelper.isSameDay(item.getDateTime(),
                    items.get(position - 1).getDateTime()))
        shouldShowHeader = true;

    if (shouldShowHeader) {
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.date.setText(DateHelper.getSimpleDate(item.getDateTime()));
    } else {
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```